# How to Build a Stable Dystopia

Tags: society, culture, inequality

I have an immortal, magically powerful character who has decided that he's had enough of the world's suffering.  He therefore sets out to unify every society in the world into a single whole with a high average quality of life.  Because he's a morally ambiguous character, he's making a society where most people live lives barely worth living, but a relative few live opulent, care-free lives.  This character also wants his society to be as stable and long-lasting as possible.

What are some features of the society that would create the highest average quality of life and also make the society stable and long-lived?  It's okay if the society changes names or form, or undergoes revolutions, so long as its main features stay fixed.  Here are some of the ideas I have so far, but if any of these are actually counter to the goal, please let me know:

- Power and wealth is in the hands of the few, but, crucially, it's technically possible to rise into the wealthy class.  This makes social mobility like the lottery:  even though basically no one will ever win it, everyone knows some people *do* win it, and this is enough to let people's dreams distract them from the reality.  This also gives those in the lower class an incentive to keep the status quo.  Shake things up and the wealth at the top will crumble, and then that dream will crumble, too.
- Constant work is emphasized in order to produce large surpluses of relatively frivolous goods.  This keeps workers tired, and gives them less mental energy to expend on finding a way out of their drudgerous labyrinth.  It also produces goods that distract them, and make their lives happier, even if those goods don't make their lives more meaningful (such as knick-knacks and cheap but pretty clothes).
- The population is spread out and information spreads slowly, and the powerful character regulates what information does spread.  This discourages the many people who are on the lowest rungs of society from unifying against the status quo.  By having all the information that reaches people be good news about the society, this also gives most people an illusion of a perfect world.  If all you see is sunshine, you'll feel a little sunny, too, and this raises average quality of life.
- Encourages tribalism between different groups within the single society and balances the tribalistic animosity.  Few things unify a group like a common enemy.

Comment: sounds like my country......even internet is watched  and censored by big brother here. even though the tyrant ruler in my country already get taken away his influence still root deep and he rule quite long. though my region is tropical so it mostly sunshine here with abundant of food variety and people did live carefree here.

Comment: This is Brave New World. Alphas at the top, each class convinced their place on the ladder is the best, consumer goods produced to keep people distracted, and hypno-propaganda to lull people into a sense of constant happy complacency. 1984 is similar, with party loyalists getting the best of things, propaganda everywhere, constant but stable war to consume resources and focus hate. 1984 had a lottery, didn't it? But no one really won.

Comment: "high average quality of life" and "most people live lives barely worth living, but a relative few live opulent, care-free lives" - the level of upper class is expected to be so high that the average level would be high instead of low?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Dystopian Stew***:

- One strong central government that controls education, information, and entertainment very tightly.
- A religion emphasizing peace and obedience, although an extreme anti-religion stance can be substituted. Anything against the system is a sin. The government should control this, but not be seen to control it.
- Several highly efficient propaganda machines. They should seem to work independently of each other, but really operate under one authority. Control everything people see, and mock and deride points of view that might disagree with the state.
- Lots of mindless entertainment for when your workers are too exhausted to work anymore. Entertainment is a branch of propaganda, and as such functions to emphasize the system and it's glories. People opposing the system are portrayed as stupid and hurtful, while all heroes are upright citizens (even when they don't seem to be, like batman)
- Be sure to add a guarantee of employment, even for the completely disabled (invent a job for everyone if needed) and support every worker in their work, but allow NO charity for the poor, no welfare, and make people completely dependent on continuous work for health, support, food, etc. Even the wealthy of your society must be kept constantly busy. Idle hands are the Devil's/anarchist's playground.
- Stir up the pot and encourage people to report on each other's antisocial behaviors. This can be one of the jobs of less able people. As technology grows, this can be taken over increasingly by devices, but still keep those snooping people at it; just confirm their reports with hard data.
- Sample the stew by having a universal testing system, evaluating everyone for jobs. It's mandatory, because employment is mandatory/guaranteed. Really smart people MUST be moved up the social ladder, but the real point is to evaluate people for potential to resist/rebel, and to reward certain classes in such a way as to increase tensions between otherwise equal social groups. In reality, the system rewards the powerful, but they also can't get complacent, as their children can be stripped of power by bad test scores (and of course, test scores must seem impartial but be under government control)
- Sprinkle with the garnish of false freedom. Maintain the illusion of democracy, because you can always blame another segment of society for anything bad or stupid that happens. "Well, of COURSE we had to eliminate food stamps! the workers voted it down as being against hard work! They don't want to support slackers!"
- Remove all external sources of independent ingredients (all other governments, religions, information, entertainment) Uncontrolled ingredients inevitably spoil the stew.
- Presentation can be critical. Create the illusion of an external threat if needed. Aliens/satanists/fairies or just the imaginary kingdom across the sea. You control education, so the kingdom across the sea is actually in your control or doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

**Western society**

Western society already ticks a lot of boxes you want. In a lot of Western countries people have many mental diseases. Depression and burn-out are rising in many countries. Both cause a tired, unhappy civilization that can't enjoy their luxuries.

Obviously this is just the beginning of your unhappy society. Monitor and restrict the internet, possibly devide it into regions and authorisation is required to go to other regions. Not knowing each other can do a lot for separating groups of people, slowing information down.

All areas are standardised. They can still have nice views, but you can just repeat the same flats and parks indefinitely. It might look nice, but you know exactly what to expect if you go to the other side of the city. The same block with the same shop and the same fountain. Only the landscape can offer some differences due to rising and falling.

Jobs can be fulfilling and worthwhile. You just need to work a lot and hard. It might not make everyone unhappy, but even doing a fulfilling job many hours a day can become boring and tire you out. Money or any equivalent is still variable, but the difference between a CEO and someone cleaning the garbage cans is at best twice as much. Everyone has a job and every other day people are required to go outside and clean an area at a set time, so all looks the same shiny way.

Social points are given and open more opportunities for you (See Black Mirror). The higher you rank, the more privileges you have. Better health care, apartment, less internet restrictions. These social points restricts a lot of behaviour and even minor ones, so you need to queue neatly, not swear and not cross a road without a zebra.

The media is controlled and shows the greatness of each region. Shows the luxuries of everyone and drills into them that this is a happy society. Otherwise it would be hate and destruction.

You can keep this up with many things. The people live in relative luxury, but even without repression you can live in relative luxury, feel society is good while being at the very least tired and not actually happy. Like a teenager in puberty, having all in the world but still everything is wrong (but without the outbursts).